# Clickable LinearLayout not flashing on click

Tags: android

In my Android app, I have a LinearLayout View that contains other views.  The LinearLayout is clickable, but when it is clicked, it does not flash orange like it should.

How can I get it to flash?

Comment: which attribute did you use in your xml? onClick or clickable?

Answer (score 5):

To produce the same flash effect you see when you click a listView item try this in your LinearLayout click handler:

```
public void onLinearLayoutClick(View v) {

  view.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.list_selector_background);

  ...
}
```

Comment: That will work. By the way behind "android.R.drawable.list_selector_background" will be such a selector Sephy is talking about. You also can take a look at this xml file in your Android SDK files in folder "platforms".

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to define 2 states for your layout if it is not natively defined for it.
Have a look [here](http://bend-ing.blogspot.com/2008/10/android-how-to-implement-custom-button.html) if you want, it explains how to do it for a button for instance.

Comment: You need to prefix the schema with xmlns: in that example.